# How to use CASE WHEN IN in Laravel database query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have `users` table and a `followers` table. I'm doing a search to get all the users with a specific keyword, but I want the ones which are followers of the current user to appear first. I can get all the followers id's in a subquery, so my idea was to do something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, surname, 
CASE WHEN id IN (SELECT followable_id FROM followers WHERE followable_id = $currentUserId --this is a variable)  THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS friend
FROM users
ORDER BY friend
WHERE name = 'keyword';
```

I've been trying to get this in my Laravel controller, but I can't find the way. **How could I use this SQL select in my Laravel controller?** **How could translate this SQL code to the [Laravel Database Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)?**

**What I have already tried:**

Following @Bassel Hossam answer, I wrote the following code:

```
$placeholders = str_repeat ('?,',  count($friendsId) - 1) . '?';
    $orderedMachingUsers = User::whereIn('id', $matchingUsersId)->select(
    [
        '*', 
        DB::raw('CASE WHEN id IN ('. $placeholders .') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS friend', $friendsId)]
)
->orderByRaw('friend')
->cursorPaginate(9);
```

It seems very very close, but I'm still geting a "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number" error. The generated SQL is the following:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
select
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN id IN (3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 111, 112, 113, 114) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS friend
from
  `users`
where
  `id` in (
    115,
    116,
    117,
    118,
    119,
    120,
    121,
    122,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?
  )
order by
  friend
limit
  10
```

It seems that somehow it's always adding the same number of question marks than the number of question marks generated in the $placeholders variable. What I can't understand is why its generating it in an array that I think that should only be related to $matchingUsersId.

dd($matchingUsersId, $friendsId) is returning the following:

```
 array:7 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 4
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 7
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 8
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 9
  ]
  5 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 10
  ]
  6 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 111
  ]
]

array:5 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 113
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 112
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 114
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 115
  ]
]
```

**Finall working code based on @Bassel Hossam answer:**

```
$placeholder = str_repeat ('?,',  count($friendsId) - 1) . '?';
        $orderedMachingUsers = User::
        whereIn('id', $matchingUsersId)->selectRaw(
            '*, CASE WHEN id IN ('. $placeholder .') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS friend', $friendsId)
    ->orderByRaw('friend DESC')
    ->simplePaginate(9);
```

Comment: Laravel doesn't support CASE statements, so you'll need to use [raw query clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: @aynber I've already tried to do it with a selectRaw(), but I can't get it working. Could you provide a solution using raw query clauses? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax for `in` condition should be like `CASE WHEN id IN (?,?,?) THEN` so you need to add `?` with the count of `$friendsId`

so you should use the following

```php
$placeholders = str_repeat ('?,',  count($friendsId) - 1) . '?';
$orderedMachingUsers = DB::table('users')
    ->whereIn('id', $matchingUsersId)->selectRaw(
            '*, CASE WHEN id IN ('. $placeholder .') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS friend', $friendsId)
    ->orderByRaw('friend')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This is very, very close! Nevertheless, it's still returning me an error. It's somehow adding the same number of question marks to the general whereIn. I updated the question with the error it's returning and some extra information that may help to see the bug. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I finally got it working with a code based on this answer. I used selectRaw() instead, which is not giving me the mentioned problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the case statement in with a raw clause

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('name', 'keyword')->select(
        [
            'id', 
            'name', 
            'surname', 
            DB::raw('CASE WHEN id IN (SELECT followable_id FROM followers WHERE followable_id = ?) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS friend', [$curentUserId])]
    )
    ->orderByRaw('friend')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems close, but I'm still geting a syntax error. I think that in your code is missing "as friend" in the raw() clause. I adapted the code, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Ah, yes, I did forget the AS clause. I'll add that in. What error are you getting?

Comment: I edited the question with the code I wrote based on your answer and the syntax error I'm getting. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full error message, as it would explain exactly what the issue is.

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_.